A smart contract already has a non-zero balance even at the start of its non-payable constructor
Solidity compiler version: 0.8.23
Foundry version: 0.2.0
When deploying a smart contract to a forked url of Sepolia, using:
console.log("Contract Balance: ",address(this).balance);
as the 1st line of code in the non-payable constructor of the contract, the printout shows there is a non-zero balance in the smart contract.
How is this possible?
When deploying the same code to Anvil, the balance shows zero, as it should be.

can you add the full code.

It's possible for a contract to have non-zero balance even without payable functions: Can a contract with no payable function have ether? .
Please check the balance of the address before you deploy - my guess is that it already has balance, for some reason. Perhaps the deployment process is deterministic and it gets deployed to a pre-known address and that address was sent assets in advance.

I am deploying with a new statement like this
